# how can i sharpen part of a mesh with the subdivision modifier

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, topology

ok I understand the title dosent make sense and mostly understand how the subdivision modifier works. I want to put subdivision on this mesh but keep these sharp parts

[image]

preferably I would like to do this while keeping the subdivision in a modifier so its togglable but I can deal with it if its not.

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YdyGSjUo5lCwuJLIRBRzCnrczgeQcvE7/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use creases.  Select the edges you want to keep sharp and increase the Crease amount (see example), and then select "Use Creases" in the modifier properties.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nlk5fgq91dl33z5/14BeforeArmWeightFix_creased.blend?dl=0)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange the topology with support edge loops like that:

[image]